# Sharepoint Online - Hide Column based on content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column, json-formatting

so basically I have a library of nested folders and a column with a request approval button.
I'd like to be able to hide the button for all folders and leave it visible for all files. I've tried a few things, but I'm really new to json and not having much luck.

```
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "#D5D5D5",
    "color": "#000",
    "padding": "4px 4px 4px 10px",
    "border-radius": "5px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Request approval"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The most common is to use the `[$File_x0020_Type]` column and check when it's blank. A method I tend to prefer, however, is to use the `[$ContentType]` column and check when it equals `Folder`.

Your format could have conditional display using an expression like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "#D5D5D5",
    "color": "#000",
    "padding": "4px 4px 4px 10px",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "display": "=if([$ContentType]=='Folder', 'none', 'inherit')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Request approval"
    }
  ]
}
```